# select non-alphabetic records in mysql

Tags: mysql, select

I want to select records that their titles don't start with a-z or 0-9 character.

One way to do this is:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE title NOT LIKE 'a%' AND... title NOT LIKE 'z%' ....
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use regular expressions:

```
select *
from table
where title regexp '^[^a-z0-9]'
```

By the way, the first `^` matches the beginning of the string.  The second is a negation of the characters in the pattern between `[` and `]`.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE (LEFT(table, 1) NOT BETWEEN 'a' AND 'z')
    AND (LEFT(table, 1) NOT BETWEEN '0' and '1')
```

Comment: +1 for Interesting solution but there are some typos. It should be LEFT(fieldName,1) and also BETWEEN '0' and '9'.